# By what is my iOS OpenGL ES 2.0 app's performance bound?

Tags: performance, ios, opengl-es, instruments, opengl-es-2.0

I'm currently learning Objective-C. As my first project, I've chosen to write a small 3D app for iOS, using only OpenGL Es 2.0. So, yes, I'm learning that at the same time. I only knew the basics of old-fashioned OpenGL (without shaders) before, but I can do (and did implement) some basic Matrix and Vector math.

I'm making some progress, but the performance isn't that great anymore. I started profiling in Instruments (Xcode 3.2; I do have access to Xcode 4 through the iOS dev program, but refrained from using that because of some strange behavior), but I can't quite make sense of the data:

The app (running on an iPhone 3GS, iOS 4.2) runs at about 15 fps, but **Device Utilization** is only around **40%**, **Renderer Utilization** around **35%**, and **Tiler Utilization** below **10%**. What does this imply? Am I bus bound? I thought I'd need to hit near 100% utilization in at least one of those three statistics before seeing the fps drop (and yes, the app can hit 60 with very simple scenes).

At the moment, all the app is doing is render a scene graph containing 500 untextured cubes with normals, bunched into groups of 1 to 6.

Comment: Given that you don't appear to be geometry (Tiler Utilization) or fill-rate (Renderer Utilization) limited, you could be CPU bound.  What does your CPU usage percentage look like in Instruments?  Does Time Profiler show any obvious hotspots?

Comment: Thank you, Brad. I was under the impression that Device Utilization meant CPU load, which it apparently doesn't - so what does it mean?. Time Profiler says my app uses a good 50% of the CPU, with SpringBoard and DTMobileIS taking another 20% each. This 90+% CPU utilization probably means I'm CPU bound. Put it up as an answer, so I can upvote you :)

Comment: @Brad - I've now gone ahead and taken a closer look at what's using the most CPU time, and it's clear: glDrawElements makes up 50% of my app's cpu utilization. This seems very high to me - shouldn't it take very little time to just send some data to the GPU?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Device Utilization is a synthesis of the Renderer and Tiler utilizations, so it shows overall how much load you're putting on the GPU.  Nominally, your application should spend a lot of time in `glDrawElements()` (mine is about 99% at fully utilization), so I'd actually check and see what was using the remaining 50%.  You might have some unnecessary state changes in there.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll go see where I can optimize my app further. Have a merry Christmas (or whatever else you're having :))!